# How to interact with the Panoramio API using services?

Tags: api, rest, service, panoramio

I'm writing a location base client and would love to integrate Panoramio with my client, now the problem is that I can't find a way to interact with the Panoramio using a ~REST-like service.

I know they do have an API but it's mostly for embedding the content into a website and not as to interact thru me code (at least from documentation)

Have any of you hacked a way thru this?

I am writing the clients natively for android and iphone in case you are wondering.

cheers,

G.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

well it seems like the answer came a bit fast... and although this is easily accessible thru their website [it is discussed](http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1473025) in their forum and even google has [posted about it](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2008/06/panoramio-api-markermanager-instant.html) in their geo developer blog

a sample request to get images from a bounding box will go along the lines of the following example:

```
http://www.panoramio.com/map/get_panoramas.php?order=popularity&set=public&from=0&to=10&minx=-124.29382324218749&miny=36.089060460282006&maxx=-119.8773193359375&maxy=38.724090458956965&callback=MyCallback
```

**Update:** I have found also [the official page](http://www.panoramio.com/api/data/api.html) to their data api.

hope it helps!

Comment: Wuau! That's a super clear and simple way to get images from Panoramio! Thanks for looking into it :D

Comment: This service is DOA!